# counting trigrams without NLTK module

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to count the trigrams in an inputed text file and return a dictionary containing the trigrams and the count of how many times they appear.

My current code is fully functional, however it is way too slow and affects the rest of my code. Please help me figure out a way to make my current code work faster or simply use a different method. Thanks!

My current (slow) code:

```
def count( txt ):

    list_s = list( s )
    count_list = []

    for i in range(len(list_s) - ( 2 ) ):

        letter = ''.join( list_s [ i:i + 3 ])
        count_list.append( letter )

        ls_to_dict = {}

        for i in count_list:

            ls_to_dict[i] = count_list.count(i)

    return ls_to_dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowness is because you're counting too many times.  Look at your loop logic: on the first iteration, you find the first trigram, and count that one.  On the 2nd iteration, you get the second trigram ... and then you count the first and second trigrams.  On the third time, you find the third trigram, and count the first three ... you have now counted the first trigram three times.

Split the logic: find all the trigram and then count them.  Also, you don't have to split the list into letter; just work with slices.

Your code won't run, by the way: decide whether your parameter is **txt** or **s**; I'll use **txt** here.

```
# Get all the trigrams
count_list = [txt[i:i+3] for i in range(len(txt)-2)]

# Count all the trigrams; use a set to avoid counting any trigram more than once.
ls_to_dict = {trigram: count_list.count(trigram) for trigram in set(count_list)}
return ls_to_dict
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!!